# Escalating user privileges on Linux

Tags: linux, privilege-escalation

I've been battling with one school task for a couple of days and can't seem to find any idea how to solve it. The task is pretty simple:

> On the server there is a secret.txt file in the /root folder, which is
> owned by root. The task is to read the contents of this file, which
> contains the answer.
> To solve the task, use one of the programs with SUID privileges to
> access the root account.

First I check which programs do have SUID privileges by using command `find / -perm /4000` which returns these programs:

```
/usr/bin/chfn
/usr/bin/umount
/usr/bin/passwd
/usr/bin/mount
/usr/bin/chsh
/usr/bin/date
/usr/bin/gpasswd
/usr/bin/newgrp
/usr/bin/procmail
/usr/lib/openssh/ssh-keysign
/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
/usr/sbin/sensible-mda
```

And I don't have any idea how to proceed with it.

Is there any way to use `procmail` to read the file while `sendmail` or `mail` don't have the privileges? I've tried to send a mail to myself with the file attached but every time I either had to use some sort of basic Linux command like `cp` or `cat` inside `.procmailrc` which resulted in `Permission Denied`, or had to use `sendmail` or `mail` which don't have the privileges for the file. Of course I don't have sudo rights. I'm just completely out of ideas on this one.

Comment: What did the class train you to do? What process have you been given to follow?

Comment: @schroeder Class was pretty straightforward. Use `find / -perm /4000` and find a program or tool with `SUID` permissions to read the file. But during the class the programs were really obvious. This homework just leaves me with zero ideas except maybe for the `procmail` usage, but reading several tutorials about it makes me think that there is no way to read text file just by using `procmail` and nothing else.

Comment: what other programs there can read files?

Comment: To be honest I don't see anything that would give me any clue except `procmail`. Everything else seems pretty standard and don't seem to be that "catch" to find in order to solve the task.

Comment: did you class cover exploting vulnerabilities?

Comment: To some extent it did, but my problem is that I have trouble identifying which program with SUID privileges should be used to read the file in this particular case.

Comment: @Paul I dunno, setuid `date` and `sensible-mda` seem suspicious to me...

Comment: Try date —help and sensible-mda —help. Do they have legitimate functionality that will read a file you specify? …

Comment: `date` is not normally a SUID tool, that makes it stand out in your list.

Comment: Do you happen to have write permissions to any of these files? (Asking the simple questions)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a very useful site called [GTFOBins](https://gtfobins.github.io) that has details about lots of different *NIX binaries, and how they can be used to privesc or perform various other actions. Going through the list of SUID binaries you have on the system and seeing if any of them have SUID entries on that site would be a good starting point, and might give you some ideas. Lots of binaries have rarely-used options that can perform actions you might not expect them to, so it can save a lot of time compared to reading through all of their manpages looking for things to try.

Otherwise, you need to look at the binaries themselves, and see if they have any functionality that you might be able to use to read files (or whatever it is that you're trying to do). Since most common binaries are likely to be included in sites like GTFOBins, if you don't find anything there then it's often good to start by looking at any more obscure or custom binaries.

Answer (score 13):

There's a fairly well-known exploit on chfn: https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5896-67mw-rv4j

> A flaw was found in the util-linux chfn and chsh utilities when compiled with Readline support. The Readline library uses an "INPUTRC" environment variable to get a path to the library config file. When the library cannot parse the specified file, it prints an error message containing data from the file. This flaw allows an unprivileged user to read root-owned files, potentially leading to privilege escalation. This flaw affects util-linux versions prior to 2.37.4.

Comment: This will depend on the version, and exploits were not yet part of the process. The class was getting them to use processes that could access files.

Answer (score 10):

Among those binaries, that `date` is setuid seems very suspicious, as spotted by [marcelm](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/99775/marcelm)

If you look at the options supported by date, it has a `-f` option which displays the time described by each line of the file.

Thus, if you run `date -f /root/secret.txt` it will open `/root/secret.txt` (since date is setuid) and will probably output an error for each line:

```
$ date -f /root/secret.txt 
date: invalid date ‘Secret answer’
date: invalid date ‘Another secret line’
```

Note that if any of the lines *is* parseable as a date by the program (for example, certain numeric lines would be interpreted as a time or date), then the output will be a date, and you would need to figure out what the initial line was.

Comment: You kinda did their homework for them. Both marcelm and I were nudging them in a direction. You provided a PoC. You provided an answer, not a method/process/mental model. Using Gh0stFish's link `date -f`would be discovered.